# How do I use a Filepicker.io widget but also use custom file names?

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

I'm currently using Filepicker.io's Javascript API and taking advantage of the ability to write custom file names to our S3 bucket using the [Store](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#store) method's Path option.  Judging by the docs online it seems that the Store method is the only place where one can actually use custom file names.

However, we'd like to start using some of the widgets or even just use the Pick/PickMultiple in the Javascript API.  Is there a way to also set custom file names while using widgets?  If so, any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this use case, you'll have to go beyond the widgets and hit the "bare metal" API, if you will. So then

```
filepicker.pick(function(FPFile){
     filepicker.store(FPFile, {location:"S3", path: "myFile.png"});
});
```

Would be the way to go about it.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for confirming, Brett.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a storePath option also:

```
filepicker.pick({storePath: '/myfiles/file.png'}, function(InkBlob) {
    console.log(InkBlob);
});
```